# FACING PROBLEM WHILE COMPARING "Hello" with "olleH"

Tags: c, if-statement, comparison, reverse, c-strings

I am trying to make a program in c where it can identify if a string is equal to its reverse or not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main(){
    char str1[10] = "Hello";
    if (str1 == strrev(str1)){
        printf("True");
    }
    else{
        printf("False");
    }
getch();
return 0;
}
```

According to my knowledge, it should print False but it is printing True instead. Can anyone fix this issue.
Thanks

Comment: In your own words, what do you expect to happen when you compare two `char*` values using `==`? Also, did you try reading the documentation for `strrev`?

Comment: Read [How do I properly compare strings in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings-in-c), then write a program checking if two strings are the same. Once you got that working, moving on to the reverse scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the function `strrev` does not create a new character array. It reverses a string in place. So in this if statement

```
if (str1 == strrev(str1)){
```

there are compared two pointers to the first element of the same character array `str1`.

To compare two strings use the standard C function `strcmp`. For example

```
char str1[10] = "Hello";
char str2[10];

strcpy( str2, str1 );

if ( strcmp( str1, strrev(str2) ) == 0 ){
    printf("True");
}
else{
    printf("False");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the operator `==` you are just comparing the `str1` memory address pointer with itself, and of course the result is true, despite the fact that the `strrev` modifies the array.
As already said by previous answers, you should create a copy of the character array `str1` and than using `strcmp` to compare the two arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's worth pointing out that it's possible to check for palindromes without having to create a copy of the original string. This would result in code that works faster and uses less memory.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int is_palindrome(const char *s) {
    int n = strlen(s);
    for (int i=0; i < n--; i++) {
        if (s[i] != s[n]) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    char *s1 = "racehorse";
    char *s2 = "racecar";
    printf("'%s' %s a palindrome\n", s1, is_palindrome(s1) ? "is" : "is not");
    printf("'%s' %s a palindrome\n", s2, is_palindrome(s2) ? "is" : "is not");
    return 0;
}
```